# Promise goes to pending state and model is not returning last inserted value

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am trying to return last inserted value using model.
my function is

```
 async addBook(data)
    {
        await db.BOOK.create(data).then((BOOK) => {
            console.log("BOOK_KEY",BOOK.BOOK_KEY);
            return BOOK.BOOK_KEY;
        })
    }
```

BOOK_KEY is not printing.

```
let bookId = this.addBook(data)
 console.log("bookId", bookId);
```

and Here bookId is going  state

```
bookId Promise { <pending> }
```

Kindly help me to display bookId. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: `let bookId = this.addBook(data)` doesn't work. `addBook` doesn't contain a return statement and doesn't return anything explicitly (it returns `undefined` implicitly).

Answer (score 0):

async function inherently returns a Promise, so you need to either use a `.then` or `await` to get the data.

```
async addBook(data) {
   const BOOK = await db.BOOK.create(data);
   return BOOK.BOOK_KEY;
}
    

let bookId = await this.addBook(data);
console.log("bookId", bookId);
```